# How is it possible for a USB device posing as a keyboard to auto-run a script without user input?

Tags: usb

I know the "USB Rubber Ducky" pretends to be a keyboard toward the OS, but I still don't understand how he can launch a script...

Normal keyboard can't just initiate keypress by itself right? Or maybe a special kind of driver is required?

Comment: Well, it can send keystrokes, so that is what it does, on windows lets send win+r c m d return e c h o space " H e l l o space W o r l d " return

Comment: As for sending keystrokes itself, why not, modern keyboards have a microcontorller that sends the keycode when button is pressed, why not just have it send a predefined list programmed into it instead?

Comment: @ewanm89 You said "modern keyboards". Can you give more details please? I personnaly think that all keyboard proceed like this.

Comment: Pretty much any keyboard you buy today will probably be a microcontroler. First keyboards were directly wired to CPU, no multiplexing, one line for every key (think early telnet terminals), then specialist integrated circuits were used for this PS2, 9-pin serial, USB, some cheaper keyboards may still use them (http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/79209.pdf). However higher end keyboards certainly use standard micro-controllers with just keyboard specific programming now it's pretty much just as cheap and allows the addition of various functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you press a key on a normal keyboard, the keyboard sends a message to the computer over USB that a key is pressed. A BadUSB device can send that same message. Instead of waiting for a keypress, it sends a couple of these messages after it has been plugged in.

So a BadUSB device doesn't just immitate a keyboard, it immitates a keyboard that has certain keys pressed in a certain order. The attacker can program [a microcontroller with USB port](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/Digispark-Kickstarter-Micro-General-USB-Development-Board-For-Arduino-ATTINY85-/351494232975) to behave as a keyboard and press some keys after some time.

Comment: I think it is worth stating that there are other attack vectors available to USB devices. However, Keyboard Emulation is one of the easier options.

Comment: Good point. A USB device can for example pretend to be a networking device and change your DNS server, so that the attacker can intercept all your network traffic.

Comment: What's more, emulate a USB hub, and then you can emulate multiple devices off it simultaneously.

Comment: Do these attack vectors are commonly used ?